# How to set properties to an object in a scene in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I have created an Scene in Qt using `QGraphicsScene`. And I have placed many objects in the scene like car , bus , etc using `QGraphicsPixmapItem`. Now I want to assign some properties to 
these objects that I placed so that i can make them run. How do I do that . For example I want to associate each object with my custom class objects . Can anyone help me . I also noticed `setData` function which associate key to value . Can this be used if so how . What's the standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If its possible to and you want to use Qt's property system, inherit from QObject as well as the QGraphicsItem.  Make sure to also define the Q_OBJECT macro.

```
class CustomPixmapItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
```